# Java return nested hashmap as string formatted as Json using Streams API

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

I have a nested HashMap declared as `Map<String, Object>`.

```
Map<String,Object> m1 = new HashMap<>();
        m1.put("name","mary");
        m1.put("email","mary@email.com");
        m1.put("address", new HashMap<>() {{
            put("firstLine", "101 Oracle");
            put("zipCode", "java 20");
        }});
```

I want to return this as a `String` in the following way without the help of an external library:

```
{
address : {
zipCode : Java 20,
firstLine : 101 Oracle
},
name : mary,
email : mary@mail.com
}
```

I cannot format the nested map in the way I want. So far I have this:

```
String s = m1.entrySet().stream()
                        .map(e -> e.getKey() + " : " + e.getValue())
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(", " + "\n", "{" + "\n", "\n" + "}"));
System.out.println(s);
```

Which gives me:

```
{
address : {zipCode=java 20, firstLine=101 Oracle}, 
name : mary, 
email : mary@email.com
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonConverter {
    public static String mapToJsonString(Map<String, Object> map) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("{");

        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            Object value = entry.getValue();

            sb.append("\"").append(key).append("\"").append(" : ");

            if (value instanceof Map) {
                // Recursively convert nested Map to JSON
                sb.append(mapToJsonString((Map<String, Object>) value));
            } else if (value instanceof String) {
                sb.append("\"").append(value).append("\"");
            } else {
                sb.append(value);
            }

            sb.append(", ");
        }

        // Remove the trailing comma and space
        if (sb.length() > 1) {
            sb.setLength(sb.length() - 2);
        }

        sb.append("}");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> m1 = new HashMap<>();
        m1.put("name", "mary");
        m1.put("email", "mary@email.com");
        m1.put("address", new HashMap<>() {{
            put("firstLine", "101 Oracle");
            put("zipCode", "java 20");
        }});

        String jsonString = mapToJsonString(m1);
        System.out.println(jsonString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slight variation.  I am using a `count` to determine when the for loop is about to finish.

- intialize a `StringBuilder` to hold the result
- then iterate thru the maps entrySet.
- if the value is a map, then append current string with a recursive call to the method.
- otherwise just process both key and value as a pair and continue
- if the loop is on the last entry, then don't attach a comma.
- near the end, some tidying up must be done to add a comma between all cases where a `"` follows a closing brace "}"

```
public static String format(Map<String, Object> map) {
    StringBuilder f = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    int maxIndex = map.entrySet().size()-1;
    for (Entry<String,Object> e : map.entrySet()) {
        boolean last = i == maxIndex;
        if (e.getValue() instanceof Map mp) {
            f.append("{")
                    .append("\"%s\": {".formatted(e.getKey()) + format(mp));
        } else {
            f.append("\"%s\" : \"%s\"%s".formatted(e.getKey(),
                    e.getValue(), last ? "" : ", "));
        }
        i++;
    }
    return f.append("} ").toString().replace("} \"", "}, \"");
}
```

With the current map structure, returns the following result.

```
{"address": {"zipCode" : "java 20", "firstLine" : "101 Oracle"}, "name" : "mary", "email" : "mary@email.com"}
```